# Why cant I and how can I concatenate a string to sliced list with python?

Tags: python

Im trying the next code:

```
lst = [1,2,3, "hi", 5]
string = "bye"
print lst[3:4].append(string)
```

By hoping get the next output:

```
["hi", "bye"]
```

But what I get is the:

```
None
```

output

Why cant I do this such of thing?
Do I have to save the list to an object before im concatenating any object to it?
Why its not like in CPP that the object returned on the place?

Comment: `append` always returns `None`. It modifies the list in-place. Try using `lst[3:4] + [string]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst[3:4]` is giving you `["hi"]`, and `.append(string)` is appending the string to that list, but the return value of `append` is `None`. You can do one of the following:

```
lst = [1,2,3, "hi", 5]
string = "bye"
lst2 = lst[3:4]
lst2.append(string)
print lst2
```

Or:

```
lst = [1,2,3, "hi", 5]
string = "bye"
print lst[3:4] + [string]
```